# Permanent Redirect in ASP.NET 4.0

Tags: asp.net, asp.net-4.0

I have heard that if you have two URL's for your site i.e. `http://yoursite.com` and `http://www.yoursite.co`m, it affects your SEO and page rank. Instead, one should do a permanent redirect from `http://` to `http://www`. Is this correct?

Now I have seen all articles showing how to do it in IIS. However I have no access to IIS.

Can anyone tell me how it is done in code behind or any other method and what's the right way to do it?

Answer (score 2):

Full domain redirects like the one you mention are best done at the IIS level, but if you aren't able to configure IIS you could use [Response.RedirectPermanent](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.web.httpresponse.redirectpermanent.aspx), which is new in ASP.NET 4.0. This will redirect with a 301 (permanent) status code instead of the 302 (object moved) status code used by a standard Response.Redirect.

What you COULD do is put something in your Global.asax "Application_BeginRequest" which checks what URL is being used and potentially uses Response.RedirectPermanent to redirect to your desired URL. This is a bit of a hack, but I suppose it would work in a pinch.

Comment: When doing permanent redirect search engines update their link cache so if 301 returned when try to access yoursite.com and redirected to www.yoursite.com it will update indexed links where as if 302 returned it will not update indexes

Answer (score 1):

inside your global.asax you can use something similar to:

```
protected void Application_BeginRequest(object sender, EventArgs e)
{
    if (!(Request.Url.AbsoluteUri.ToLower().Contains("www")))
    {
      Response.RedirectPermanent(Request.Url.AbsoluteUri.Replace("http://", "http://www."));
    }
}
```

Comment: Response.Redirect will use a 302 status code, whereas if you did basically this but with a Response.RedirectPermanent (see my answer) it will redirect correctly with a 301.

Comment: Thanks. So there is no penalty from Search Engines if I do this now. My site is up from the past 2 years.

Comment: There shouldn't be. You might also check out Google's Webmaster Tools, as they will give you loads of information about how Google sees your site and reveal potential issues such as this one. Check out www.google.com/webmasters/.

Comment: Ok one last question. Is there any additional advantage if I somehow convince my host do it through IIS and not code?